# php version upgrade cause an error for old program

Tags: php, xampp

I just installed xampp, to run some old program (created 2 or more years ago) and I'm getting 3 errors I can't figure out.

> 1. Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\2010\web\core\route\route.php on line 117

```
    public function loadClass($address,$ext='') {
        $this->extname = preg_replace('/_/','/',$address,3);
line:117>       $this->classname = end(explode('_',$address)).($e= $ext!='' ? '('.$ext.')' :  '');
        include_once(ROOT_ROUTE.'/'.$this->extname.'.php');
        $this->newclass = new $this->classname;
        return $this->newclass;
    }
```

the line 117 i can't understand, it is not using passed by reference, why there is a error?

Comment: Which line is line 117 in this case?

Comment: $this->classname = end(explode('_',$address)).($e= $ext!='' ? '('.$ext.')' :  '');

Comment: What does the end function look like?

Comment: @DWight - I'm guessing that it's PHP's end() function - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because end() expects an argument passed by reference, you can't use it with a non-variable such as the direct result of another function call or construct.

Quoting from the argument definition in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php):

> This means you must pass it a real variable and not a function returning an array because only actual variables may be passed by reference.

Change

```
$this->classname = end(explode('_',$address)).($e= $ext!='' ? '('.$ext.')' :  '');
```

to

```
$addressTemp = explode('_',$address);
$this->classname = end($addressTemp) . ($e= $ext!='' ? '('.$ext.')' :  '');
```